# Semantic PDF to HTML conversion

Tags: pdf, conversion, html

I would like to convert a PDF document to a collection of HTML pages that exhibit 'clean' markup, and generate/keep semantic info (chapters, sections...), as well as perform cleanup tasks (e.g. I am not interested in page numbers, or repeating the title of the chapter/document on each page).

Is there any such program?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Calibre allows conversion of a pdf to htlmz format which is a single file html page with data.
if you wanted to use it to create a collection of html pages, you would need to split the pdf up first depending upon your operating system.
Calibre works on all major operating systems, install the program from http://calibre-ebook.com
import the pdf, then use 'convert books' option from ui and choose htmlz format. There are several settings pages that can be altered to get your final result

There is also a command line interface if this is something you'ld like to script up.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one, because I needed it for my website [schooletc.co.uk](http://schooletc.co.uk) transcribing hundred thousands PDFs into semantic HTML without making a huge mess.

Here's my Github repository https://github.com/fmalina/transcript

It is a two step process, first the PDFs are processed using PDFtoHTML(Ex) which produces presentational HTML markup, than the documents are processed using transcript.py producing semantic HTML including headings, paragraphs, lists and data tables.